# Using HTML with specific JSF and/or PrimeFaces components

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've been mostly writing in JSF and PF but I'm missing practical examples or tutorials of how to integrate JSF and HTMl. For example, when using a datatable ()is it possible to simply use a standard html tag () and embed the bean logic like this?

```
  // The JSF data table 
    <h:dataTable value="#{someBean.myList}" var="list"> 
<h:columns>
<h:outputText value="#{list.someValue}"/>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>

// How can this adapted to HTML?
<table> #{someBean.myList} 
<th> the Header </th>
<td> #{list.someValue} </td>
</table>
```

I like using JSF and PF but some web designers find HTML more flexible for CSS designs and such. Also I don't want to rely on any single framework for my own web development.

It would be useful to know how to integrate HTML into JSF with practical examples specifically related to server side operations like data tables, drop down lists, etc. The material I've read and the online content I didn't come accross specific data examples to help me grasp the idea in a practical way.

Comment: I can hardly believe there is nothing to be found in the internet about displaying a list from jsf/el with plain html table. Hint: `ui:repeat`

Comment: And in more general terms…  jsf/facelets is an html generator is this refard. Plain jsf components render plain html on the client. Please learn a little about the technology you are using

Comment: Thanks for your comments Kukeltje. I have not given enough attention to the design part of jsf and to be honest everything on the net is patchy and inconsistent on this subject. I will make more effort to learn of course but that's probably going to happen by practical examples unless a good html5 jsf tutorial can be recommended (as I asked in my question). Thanks again